# Migrate C to C# problem!

Tags: c#, c

I try to convert C lib to C# and got stuck in this code:

```
typedef struct _Symbol
{
    unsigned char value;
    unsigned char count;
    unsigned char under;
    unsigned char left, right;
} Symbol;

// [...]
```

void function(Symbol * symbol) {

...

```
if (! symbol -> right) break; // So, right is equivalent to bool in C#?

symbol += symbol -> right; // I have no idea what this code will do.
```

...

}

Please help me out.

Comment: an unsigned char in c# would be a byte. The code you have there checks to see if right is greater than zero.

Comment: I suspect that symbol is defined as Symbol* symbol and that left and right are offsets to to instances of Symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ any object that has a comparison operator, and can be compared against '0' can be used in an expression in a conditional. If the expression equals 0 then the expression will evaluate to false, otherwise the expression will evaluate to true.

So: `if(!symbol->right)` will be true if symbol->right is 0.

The following

```
symbol += symbol->right
```

is incrementing the symbol pointer by the value stored in symbol->right.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now. So, in C# I should replace 'unsigned char right' with 'Symbol right'.

Answer (score 5):

In C# there is no `->` operator. To reference a struct member you use `.` operator. Also, you can't use any expression with `if` sentences. You **must** use a proper boolean expression:

```
if (symbol.right == 0)
    break;
```

Also, I wouldn't try to convert **line-by-line** a C program into a C# program. They are based on different paradigms, so you would probably need to learn a little bit of object orientation and how C# manages memory before attempting to translate code.

Comment: Thanks, I know C# and new to C. C is some kind of ancient programming language but it is interesting.

Answer (score 4):

`if (! symbol -> right) break;` says if right is zero then break

`symbol += symbol -> right;` this is performing pointer arithmetic, you'll need to understand why so you can recode it into C#. (assuming symbol is of type `Symbol*`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
struct Symbol
{
Char value;
int  count; // if your counting, use an integer, not a character
int  under; // not sure that is supposed to represent
int left; 
int right;
}
```

I'm not sure what you want or need the right and left data members to do. It looks like you wanted to at least increment them, so I left them as integers.
In which case you can't just test it using if (symbol.left), but rather you have to use if (symbol.left > 0) etc...

Also C# doesn't use the -> operator, but the . operator exclusively.

In .NET all types cannot just be cast into other types willy nilly. So you can't convert a character (Char in C#) into a bool, or an int.

If you want to keep using C, and still take advantage of .NET you can use the managed compiler /clr and compile all your C Code. But you will have to learn a few extra language keywords, and program a little different.

In general if you are really new to C# and .NET I highly suggest you get two books. The first book is on .NET by Jeffrey Richter (CLR via C#). It's published by Microsoft Press, and is excellent. The other book can or should be C# specific. Charles Petzold has a good introductory book to C# called Programming in the key of C#, that is pretty basic for the language.

Answer (score 0):

left and right are defined in the struct:

```
unsigned char left, right;
```

It is not the wrong, right "right" but left,right right :)

And its equivalent in C# is not bool.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if (!symbol->right) break
```

checks if the *character* held in the variable *right* is null (equals '\0'). So, if the character is equal to 0, it will break, otherwise it won't.

Answer (score 0):

> if (! symbol -> right) break;

I believe this is boolean NOT operation on char in int context.
Eg: if (int)right = 0, this is true. Otherwise, it's false.